# I have to find the balance parenthesis. but its showing wrong answer for one test case

Tags: java

*I have to calculate the valid parenthesis but one test case is missing.. and I don't know how the output is "True" for this test case only*

*input : ([}}])   output:- true,    Expected output : false*

```
`class Solution {
    public boolean isValid(String s) {
        Stack <Character> st = new Stack<>();
        int len = s.length();
        if(len%2!=0){
            return false;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)=='(' || s.charAt(i)=='{' || s.charAt(i)=='['){
                st.push(s.charAt(i));
            }

            else if(!st.isEmpty() && s.charAt(i)==')'){
                if(!st.isEmpty() && st.peek()=='('){
                    st.pop();
                }
            }

            else if(!st.isEmpty() && s.charAt(i)=='}'){
                if(st.peek()=='{'){
                    st.pop();
                }
            } 

            else if(!st.isEmpty() && s.charAt(i)==']'){
                if(st.peek()=='['){
                    st.pop();
                }
            }
        }
        if(st.isEmpty() ){
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
}`
```

*I am trying the output "false" but it's showing "true".*

Comment: hmm .. this feels like a repost .. is it?

Comment: Not as of now..

Comment: I hope this was not your school h/w :( try to solve those your self . If you cant might be good to consider testing instead of software dev or get in to a support or proj mt role. just my 2 cents

Comment: This seems to be a common problem at coding practice / challenge sites. Can you, please, give us a link to the page where you found the problem?

Comment: Hmmm -- Looks like there are several questions on Stack Overflow about checking balanced parentheses: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+balanced+parentheses

Comment: Please edit the question to describe your efforts to debug this. A question about code with bugs is more likely to draw good answers if the person asking documents efforts to debug.  It might help to read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your only coding for the positive cases. Do a truth table, go through the code for every entry in  your example. you need to keep a flag when you get a closing bracket but you do  not have a opening bracket. right now your just ignoring it. I have not tested below code for all test cases, but you can add test cases to it.

```
package sel2in.academic;

import java.util.Stack;

public class    CheckBrackets {


        public boolean isValid(String s) {
            Stack<Character> st = new Stack<>();
            int len = s.length();
            if(len%2!=0){//why? can have a string like "{s}" ?
                //return false;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
                if(s.charAt(i)=='(' || s.charAt(i)=='{' || s.charAt(i)=='['){
                    st.push(s.charAt(i));
                }

                else if(!st.isEmpty() && s.charAt(i)==')'){
                    if(!st.isEmpty() && st.peek()=='('){
                        st.pop();
                    }else{
                      return false; /// need similar in other places too
                }

                else if(!st.isEmpty() && s.charAt(i)=='}'){
                    if(st.peek()=='{'){
                        st.pop();
                    }
                }

                else if(!st.isEmpty() && s.charAt(i)==']'){
                    if(st.peek()=='['){
                        st.pop();
                    }
                }else  if(s.charAt(i)==')' || s.charAt(i)=='}' || s.charAt(i)==']'){//missing test, might be more do more truth tables
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(st.isEmpty() ){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckBrackets app = new CheckBrackets();
        app.tesCases();
    }

    private  void tesCases() {
            test("{}", true);
        test("{x}", true);
        test("{}}", false);
        System.out.println("Remember for failed test cases check the test case and the logic");
        System.out.println("test cases " + testCases + " fails :" + failedTestCases);
    }
    int testCases = 0;
        int failedTestCases=0;
    private void test(String testStr, boolean expectedValue) {
        testCases++;
            boolean actualResult = false;
            try {
                actualResult=isValid(testStr);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exce " + e + ", input str :" + testStr + "; expected :" + expectedValue);
            }
            if(actualResult != expectedValue){
                failedTestCases++;
                System.out.println("failed test Case, input str :" + testStr + "; expected :" + expectedValue  + " actual :"+ actualResult);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: please take the time to write real English words (vs. the non-existing _thru_ or _ur_)